# Click button that fills input & submits

Tags: javascript, onclick

First off, let me say I'm very much new to Javascript, and relatively clueless when it comes to the backend of the application I recently had developed. I'm working on the front-end design/minor functionality. So, if you could please keep that in mind with your answers, that'd be much appreciated!

I have an input field where a user can enter an address, and click submit to bring up a property results page.

```
<input type='text' class='main-search-address' id="main-search-address" placeholder="Enter Street Address">in Seattle, WA
<input value="Search" type="submit" class="submit" id='main-search'>
```

On the results page, there is a section where nearby addresses are displayed, via AJAX/js like so:

```
<span id="nearby_address">this gets replaced with an address</span>
```

For example

```
<span>1103 YAKIMA AVE S</span>
```

I'm looking for some javascript that will allow me to click the address in the span tag, have it paste into the input above, and automatically 'submit'-- all with one click.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry that you're new, but SO is not a site for getting people to write code for you. You have to make an attempt first. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I'm still learning how this community helps each other as well. I'll be sure to keep this in mind next time I post.

Answer (score 0):

Change your search button code to:

```
<input value="Search" type="submit" name="submitSearch" class="submit" id='main-search'>
```

And your span code to:

```
<span id="nearby_address" onclick="FillSub()">
```

And then use this javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function FillSub(){
var elem = document.getElementById("nearby_address").innerHTML;
var elem2 = document.getElementById("main-search-address");
elem2.value = elem;
document.NAME-OF-YOUR-FORM.submitSearch.click();
}
</script>
```

You should do a bit research before you ask a question next time. I was just curious how would I solve this myself, so I did. Edit the last value of the script, because you didn't post the name of your `<form>`.

Comment: You haven't bound any of this to a click handler. It will run the Javascript as soon as the page is loaded, not when the user clicks on the nearby address.

Comment: You can just use `document.NAME-OF-FORM.submit()` instead of giving a name to the submit button.

Comment: Thanks @Eda190, I don't have the inputs wrapped in a <form> tag. I tried, but, for some reason, it no longer works.

Comment: Form has to have `action` that is name of other file (or empty brackets to call the same file you put it in) that you post your form data to.

Comment: @user1661677 Your question says you want it to be submitted automatically. If you don't have a form, what should be submitted and where? The alternative to using a form is to write AJAX code in Javascript.